# High accuracy during training and validation, low accuracy during prediction with the same dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

So I'm trying to train Keras model. There is high accuracy (I'm using f1score, but accuracy is also high) while training and validating. But when I'm trying to predict some dataset I'm getting lower accuracy. Even if I predict training set. So I guess it's not about overfitting problem. What then is the problem?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    X_train,x_val,y_train,y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.5,stratify = y_train)
    y_train = encode(y_train)
    y_val = encode(y_val)
    
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(50,input_dim=X_train.shape[1],activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(25,activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(10,activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))   
    
    opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['acc', ta.utils.metrics.f1score])  
    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
                        validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
                        epochs=5000,
                        verbose=0)
    
    plt.plot(history.history['f1score'])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_f1score'])
    plt.title('model accuracy')
    plt.ylabel('f1score')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
    plt.show()
    break
```

The result is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaVUB.png). As you can see results high at training and validation set.

And code for predict:

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

y_pred = model.predict(x_train)
y_pred = decode(y_pred)
y_train_t = decode(y_train)
print(f1_score(y_train_t, y_pred))
```

The result is 0.64, that is less than expected 0.9.

My decode and encode:

```
def encode(y):
    Y=np.zeros((y.shape[0],2))
    for i in range(len(y)):
        if y[i]==1:
            Y[i][1]=1
        else :
            Y[i][0]=1
    return Y

def decode(y):
    Y=np.zeros((y.shape[0]))
    for i in range(len(y)):
        if np.argmax(y[i])==1:
            Y[i]=1
        else :
            Y[i]=0
    return Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use a last layer of

```
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax')
```

you should **not** use `loss='binary_crossentropy'` in `model.compile()`, but `loss='categorical_crossentropy'` instead.

Due to this mistake, the results shown during model fitting are probably wrong - the results returned by sklearn's `f1_score` are the real ones.

Irrelevant to your question (as I guess the follow-up  one will be *how to improve it?*), we practically never use `activation='tanh'` for the hidden layers (try `relu` instead). Also, dropout should *not* be used by default (especially with such a high value of 0.5); comment-out all dropout layers and only add them back if your model overfits (using dropout when it is not needed is known to hurt performance).

Comment: Thank you for your tips, I appreciate that! I changed loss to `categorical_crossentropy`, removed dropouts and f1_score become like this https://imgur.com/HMSndRj . I guess it's now overfitting problem. On training set predict gives 100% f1_score. But on testing set f1_score is much lover (0.41).

Comment: @Leerion as said, if you suspect overfitting, then you may start adding dropout layers, gradually and starting from low dropout values. But here it would seem that you are in a class imbalance setting, which further complicates things. Experiment is king...

Comment: @Leerion your plot shows a test F1 ~ 0.90, not 0.41

Comment: sorry, misleading labels. The blue line shows F1 score on a training set, the orange line shows F1 score on a validation set. After model is compiled, it's predicting testing set and the result is 0.41 of F1 score.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should change the `binary_crossentropy` to `categorical_crossentropy` since you use one-hot encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, the combination of image generator and the predict_generator() function or the predict() function of Keras' model does not work as expected.
Rather than using image generator to do prediction, I'd rather loop through all test images one-by-one and get the prediction for each image in each iteration. I am using Plaid-ML Keras as my backend and to get prediction I am using the following code.

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import keras
import numpy

###
# I am not including code to load models or train model
###

print("Prediction result:")
dir = "/path/to/test/images"
files = os.listdir(dir)
correct = 0
total = 0
#dictionary to label all traffic signs class.
classes = {
    0:'This is Cat',
    1:'This is Dog',
}
for file_name in files:
    total += 1
    image = Image.open(dir + "/" + file_name).convert('RGB')
    image = image.resize((100,100))
    image = numpy.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    image = numpy.array(image)
    image = image/255
    pred = model.predict_classes([image])[0]
    sign = classes[pred]
    if ("cat" in file_name) and ("cat" in sign):
        print(correct,". ", file_name, sign)
        correct+=1
    elif ("dog" in file_name) and ("dog" in sign):
        print(correct,". ", file_name, sign)
        correct+=1
print("accuracy: ", (correct/total))
```